# package org.hamcrest does not exist

Tags: java, maven, hamcrest

I'm getting the error `java: package org.hamcrest does not exist`.
The POM file looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In ones of the tests, I have this import which is causing the error:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```

I'm using IntelliJ 2017.3.4

I've tried removing the `scope` tag and have changed it to `compile`, and importing other `hamcrest` packages like `hamcrest.core`. Also, running `mvn clean` and rebuilding the project did not work.

Comment: Are these dependencies wrapped inside `<dependencyManagement/>` ?

Comment: No, they are inside the `<project>` tags

Comment: Are you using mockito? Mockito packages its own `org.hamcrest` package into lib. As I remember, this package was part of JUnit too some time, dont know, if it is still issue. Try to move your hamcrest-all dependency definition to first place in `dependencies` section (before mockito and junit dependencies)

Comment: @Bedla I'm not using Mockito. Moving the package before JUnit doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually deleting the `.idea` folder and rebuilding worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to delete it from local repo (which us usually under ~/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/) and try to build project again.

Answer (score 0):

/apache-ignite-2.8.0-src/modules/indexing/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/IgniteDynamicSqlRestoreTest.java:[52,27] package org.hamcrest does not exist

Got this same error.

When the .m2/repository was cleared and rebuilt - the issue got resolved